# Why twitter 'status->content' i.e. timeline is saved very odd into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, twitter

My app saves tweets into mysql. But the contents of '$status->content' i.e. tweet message are not saved as they appear if outputted. Other values like '?->author->name' and '?->id' are saved as they appear. This is how a tweet msg i.e. '$status->content'  look like when I display tables results;

```
<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23DIYse_D" onclick="pageTra
cker._setCustomVar(2, 'result_type', 'recent', 3);pageTracker._trackPageview('/i
ntra/hashtag/#DIYse_D');"><b>#DIYse_D</b></a>  D
```

The results are returned as xml object from my php function & I fetch values of these properties from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because there is HTML (with a page tracker) in the content. If you look at the [original results](http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23DIYse_D) source, you can see that "status" has a type of "html".

Use:

```
$clean_content = strip_tags($status->content);
```

To remove HTML tags and obtain only the text.